# Laravel - Find user id of logged in user and get a value from another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table that contains the column value of one table and the column value of another, the name is property_users
This is `property_users` column names
`id` ,`user_id` ,`property_id`

`user_id` and `property_id` automatically fills based on the id from `users table` and `properties table` respectively
How can I get the `property_id` from the `property_users` table based on the logged in user's `user_id` in the table

Comment: Can you share your models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make model `PropertyUser` for table `property_users` (it must extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class) and get properties by

```
$properties = PropertyUser::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

thats all

Comment: Thank you vey much

Comment: after getting the row based on the properties statement, how can i get the property_id field in particular

Comment: `foreach($properties as $property) { $id = $property->property_id; ...}`